# CERTAIN tab characters don't match in shell scripts, but do on command-line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, zsh, dash-shell

I'm trying to do some simple parsing of the output of the `xinput` command in a shell script.  What I am trying to do works perfectly on the commandline, but doesn't work in the script.

Here is my commandline:

```
xinput list | awk '/Name of my Device   id[0-9]*    \[slave pointer/'
```

The output of the previous command:

```
⎜   ↳ Name of my Device      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

When at the prompt, I input the tabs by hitting **CTRL-V,TAB**.  When in the script, I input a line which reads:

```
xinput list | awk '/Name of my Device   id[0-9]*/'
```

Which returns three lines of data.  As soon as I add another tab, like so:

```
xinput list | awk '/Name of my Device   id[0-9]*    /'
```

I no longer get any output.  I tried with both **CTRL-V,TAB** and just with **TAB**.  I've also tried manually typing the whole script line from scratch in case there was a non-printable in there somewhere.  Why is `awk` able to deal with the first tab, but not the second?  BTW, I've tried this with dash, bash, and zsh.  The behavior is identical.

Thank you very much.

P.S. I forgot to mention my editor is vim.

P.P.S

```
xinput list | awk '/Name of my Device   id[0-9]*    \[slave pointer/' |
    sed 'y/ \t/_$/'
```

outputs:

```
⎜___↳_Name_of_my_Device$id=12$[slave__pointer__(2)]
```

Comment: What is the output of `xinput list`

Comment: Can you save the output of `xinput list` to a file and then cat the file with `cat -t` so we can see the tabs (and add it into your question)?

Comment: Did one better.  Marked the spaces and tabs.  If you want me to mark the other non-printables, I can.

Comment: Okay, well that had me stumped for a bit, but in the end it's just a typo. You're missing the `=` in `id[0-9]*`.  Try with `xinput list | awk '/Name of my Device   id=[0-9]*    /'` and you should be fine.

Comment: Also, you might find it easier to use `\t` instead of literal tabs:  `awk '/Name of my Device\tid=[0-9]*\t/'`  should work just as well.

Comment: @jas You're a lifesaver.  However, it did not work when I used `\t` for some reason.   Does start working with the `=` sign.  Don't know why it *doesn't* work without the tab ***and*** without the `=` sign, though.

Comment: Without the tab and without the `=` it works because `id[0-9]*` matches `id` followed by _zero_ or more digits, so the presence of the `=` doesn't kill the match.  Once you add the `<tab>`, though, the `=` gets in the way!

Comment: This will illustrate what's being matched in that case: `echo '   ↳ Name of my Device id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]' | awk '{sub(/Name of my Device id[0-9]*/, "XXX"); print}'`

Comment: If you put in an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the extra tab was a bit of a red herring. Really it was a missing `=` in the pattern that was causing the problem:

```
xinput list | awk '/Name of my Device id=[0-9]* /'
```

is the corrected version.

Without the `<tab>` and without the `=` it works because `id[0-9]*` matches `id` followed by *zero or more* digits, so the presence of the `=` doesn't kill the match. Once you add the `<tab>`, though, the `=` gets in the way.

running

```
echo ' ↳ Name of my Device  id=12   [slave pointer (2)]' | awk '{sub(/Name of my Device id[0-9]*/, "XXX"); print}'
```

will illustrate what was getting matched when both the `=` and `<tab>` were missing.